# Cookie is not expired, but it doesn't work after 10 minutes in .NET 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cookies

use cookies for my project. When I set a cookie for a user, I use this method to check the user is authenticated or not.

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return Ok(new ResponseDto { IsSuccessFull = false, Message = ErrorsMessages.NotAuthenticated, Status = "NotAuthenticated" });
                }
                var claims = User.Identities.First().Claims.ToList();
                var user = claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;
                var result = await _userRepository.GetUserAllDetailsByMobileAsync(user);
                return Ok(new ListResponseDto<GetUserWithReservationDto> { IsSuccessFull = true, Data = result, Message = ErrorsMessages.Authenticated, Status = "Authenticated" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the request.");
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new ListResponseDto<Exception> { IsSuccessFull = false,Data=ex, Message = "An error occurred.", Status = "Error" });

            }
        }
```

and its work fine
but after 10 this method return NotAuthenticated

Note: This problem does not occur on localhost.

this is my program.cs

Note: This problem does not occur on localhost.

```
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Lakoode.Models.Context;
using Lakoode.Repository.GenericRepository;
using Lakoode.Repository.Implementation.Account;
using Lakoode.Repository.Implementation.Reservation;
using Lakoode.Repository.Implementation.Villa;
using Lakoode.Repository.Interfaces.Account;
using Lakoode.Repository.Interfaces.Reservation;
using Lakoode.Repository.Interfaces.Villa;
using Lakoode.Utilities.SmsSender;
using Lakoode.Utilities.Utiliteis;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<LakoodeDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);

builder.Services.AddCors(c =>
{
    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.WithOrigins("https://lakoode.ir")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});

builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(options =>
                {
                    options.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    options.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                }
                
                )
                    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true);


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;



}).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/SignOut";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{

    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Lakoode Service", Version = "v1" });
});
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISmsSender, SmsSender>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaRepsoitory, VillaRepsoitory>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IReservationRepository, ReservationRepository>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));



var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

i change cookie expire time to 30 days but is not work

Answer (score -1):

```
    The behavior you are describing, where authentication works fine on localhost but not on a deployed server, can be caused by a variety of issues. Here are some common reasons why this might happen and the Solution

    1. Cookie Domain Mismatch:
    When setting a cookie, ensure that the domain is correctly configured, especially when transitioning from localhost to a deployed environment. If the cookie domain is set to localhost and you deploy the application to a different domain, the cookie might not be sent with the request, causing the user to appear unauthenticated.
   
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Domain = "yourdomain.com"; // Update this with your actual domain
            // other options...
        });
    
    2. SSL/HTTPS Issues:
    Browsers have different policies for cookies in secure contexts. If your application is deployed with HTTPS, make sure that the requests are also made using HTTPS. Some browsers block third-party cookies in insecure contexts.
    
    Solution: Ensure your application is served over HTTPS and all requests are made securely.
    
    3. Cookie Expiration:
    If the cookie has a short expiration time, users might be getting logged out after a certain period of time.

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Set your desired expiration time
        // other options...
    });
4. Load Balancer or Proxy Server Issues:
If your application is behind a load balancer or proxy server, make sure they are configured to pass along the necessary headers, including secure cookies.

5. Anti-virus or Browser Extensions:
Sometimes, anti-virus programs or browser extensions can interfere with cookies.

Solution: Temporarily disable anti-virus and browser extensions to see if they are causing the issue.
6. Session Data Loss:
If your application uses session state, check if the session data is being lost due to misconfigurations or server restarts.
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); // Set your desired session timeout
});

7. Firewall or Security Group Issues:
Ensure that there are no firewall rules or security group settings that block cookies or certain HTTP headers.

8. Browser Cache:
Sometimes, browser cache can cause unexpected behavior. Try clearing your browser cache or testing in an incognito/private browsing window.

9. Cookie SameSite Attribute:
Modern browsers have started enforcing the SameSite attribute for cookies. This attribute can prevent third-party cookies from being sent in cross-site requests.
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        // other options...
    });
```